# How to generate custom sequence number in SQL Server within a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a employee data

```
   EmployeeNum | Department | Salary
     1000      |     1      | 400
     1001      |     1      | 200
     1002      |     2      | 350
     1003      |     2      | 450
```

And I want to get sum of the salary by the department and the salary per employee in one select query. The expected output is

```
SQNO   |  EmployeeNum   | Department   | Salary
 1     |  1000          |     1        |  400
 2     |  1001          |     1        |  200
       |                |     1        |  600
 3     |  1002          |     2        |  350
 4     |  1003          |     2        |  450
       |                |     2        |  800
```

My approach is

```
select 
    case 
       when EmployeeNum is null 
          then null 
          else ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Department) 
    end as SQNO,
    EmployeeNum,
    Department,
    SUM(Salary)
from 
    EMPDetails
group by 
    GROUPING sets(EmployeeNum, Department), (Department)
```

The output of this select is

```
SQNO   |  EmployeeNum   | Department   | Salary
 1     |  1000          |     1        |  400
 2     |  1001          |     1        |  200
       |                |     1        |  600
 4     |  1002          |     2        |  350
 5     |  1003          |     2        |  450
       |                |     2        |  800
```

Is there a way to skip row numbers as we desire or any other idea how to do this?.

Comment: I am happy with your question and answered it as well but in my opinion the title is totally misleading. Anything like "complex sum over a group" would be much closer to your real question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `DENSE_RANK()` and additional `order by` clause at the bottom:

```
 select 
    case 
       when EmployeeNum is null 
          then null 
          else dense_rank() over (order by EmployeeNum) 
    end as SQNO,
    EmployeeNum,
    Department,
    SUM(Salary)
from 
    EMPDetails
group by 
    GROUPING sets(EmployeeNum, Department), (Department)
order by department
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility that returns what you want

```
DECLARE @T AS TABLE (EmployeeNum INT, Departement INT, Salary INT)
INSERT INTO @T VALUES (1000,1,400),(1001,1,200), (1002,2,350), (1003,2,450)

SELECT a.SQNO, a.EmployeeNum, a.Departement, a.Salary
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS dummy, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DEPARTEMENT) SQNO, EmployeeNum, Departement, Salary
    FROM @T
    UNION
    SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, Departement, SUM(Salary)
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY Departement
    ) AS a
ORDER BY Departement,a.dummy
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
emps.seqn, 
emps.EmployeeNum, 
CASE WHEN emps.Department IS NULL THEN outere.Department ELSE emps.Department END AS DEP, 
CASE WHEN emps.salary IS NULL THEN outere.TOTALSUM ELSE emps.salary END AS salary
FROM (
    SELECT  *, row_number(  ) over(order by Department, EmployeeNum) as seqn from EMPDetails
) emps
FULL JOIN (SELECT Department, SUM(salary) as TOTALSUM, -1 as a from EMPDetails GROUP BY Department) outere
ON  emps.salary = outere.a 
ORDER BY DEP, CASE WHEN EmployeeNum IS NOT NULL THEN EmployeeNum ELSE 9223372036854775807 END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Use CTE method to get tolal for each department :

;WITH CTE (_Id , SQNo , EmployeeNum , Departement ,  Salary ) AS 
 (
   SELECT 0, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DEPARTEMENT) SQNO, EmployeeNum,   
   Departement, Salary FROM your_table
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1, NULL SQNO, NULL EmployeeNum, Departement, SUM(Salary) Salary
   FROM your_table
   GROUP BY Departement
 ) 

SELECT SQNo , EmployeeNum , Departement ,  Salary 
FROM  CTE ORDER BY Departement,_Id ASC
```